# Validation in asp.net using asp controls

Tags: asp.net, validation

For validation of expression in asp.net, what does this mean? I found this online to check the expression.

```
[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$")]
```

Comment: [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a very useful site with respect to Regex.  I would have thought that you'd have Binged or Googled such a question first, though.

Comment: what exactly you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

This is an `Attribute` denoted by `[...]`. The RegularExpression contained inside it is used to compare any strings against it and either accept the string or reject it.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx)

```
Specifies that a data field value in ASP.NET Dynamic Data must match the 
specified regular expression.
```

Example

The following example shows how to use the RegularExpressionAttribute attribute to validate the FirstName and LastName data fields. The regular expression allows up to 40 uppercase and lowercase characters. The example performs the following tasks:
•
Implements a metadata partial class and the associated metadata class. 
•
In the associated metadata class, applies the RegularExpressionAttribute attribute to the FirstName and LastName data fields, specifying the pattern and custom error messages.

```
   using System;
   using System.Web.DynamicData;
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


   [MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))]
   public partial class Customer
   {


   }

   public class CustomerMetaData
   {

       // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase  
       // characters. Use custom error.
       [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", 
            ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
       public object FirstName;

       // Allow up to 40 uppercase and lowercase  
       // characters. Use standard error.
       [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
       public object LastName;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seema, why dont you do some homework @ [Regexlib](http://regexlib.com/%28A%28K3dYCiXq6B_RiiOprBynEXSc68xXZtNlcGGcHq94reS_kycg9RjAdxrtrSlxGphm4tIyn04Hw543PkIVZSSnUfCTsC3jcvWhLxNDyTCmcpThl9O4Eu-PV7zKdE9sJ2YGtKqoczRLwrWMN03xJfK8Mx5vUdFkct4qXqGQKyYlwF9PFPhu2d013DLsDiYWVKrZ0%29%29/CheatSheet.aspx)